# Does Dart have a comma operator?

Tags: dart

Consider the following line of code that doesn't compile in Dart -- lack of comma operator, but comparable things are totally fine in JavaScript or C++:

```
final foo = (ArgumentError.checkNotNull(value), value) * 2;
```

The closest I could get with an ugly workaround is

```
final foo = last(ArgumentError.checkNotNull(value), value) * 2;
```

with function

```
T last<T>(void op, T ret) => ret;
```

Is there a better solution?

Comment: Define "better solution". Is there a particular effect you are going for or are you merely trying to recreate this specific usage of the comma operator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dart does not have a comma operator similar to the one in JavaScript.

There is no obviously better solution than what you already have.

The work-around operation you introduced is how I would solve it. I usually call it `seq` for "sequence" if I write it.

There is sadly no good way to use an extension operator because you need to be generic on the second operand and operators cannot be generic. You could use an extension method like:

```dart
extension Seq on void {
  T seq<T>(T next) => next;
}
```

Then you can write `ArgumentError.checkNotNull(value).seq(value)`.

(For what it's worth, the `ArgumentError.checkNotNull` function has been changed to return its value, but that change was made after releasing Dart 2.7, so it will only be available in the next release after that).

Comment: I like the extension chaining!

Comment: Also coming in future versions of Dart: nullable and non-nullable variable types.

Comment: @Abion47 NNBD is may #1 missing feature in Dart. #2 are union and intersection types.

Answer (score -1):

If the overhead doesn't matter, you can use closures without arguments for a similar effect (and also more complex operations than just a sequence of expressions).

```
final foo = () {
  ArgumentError.checkNotNull(value);
  return value;
} ();
```

This is not great for hot paths due to the overhead incurred by creating and calling a closure, but can work reasonably well outside those.

If you need this kind of test-plus-initialization pattern more than once, the cleanest way would arguably be to put it in a function of its own, anyway.

```
T ensureNotNull<T>(T value) {
  ArgumentError.checkNotNull(value);
  return value;
}

final foo = ensureNotNull(value);
```